# MSM, Error 500 and Custom Config

Tags: multi-site-manager

I'm currently running my custom bootstrap config, and I had a previous problem where MSM wouldn't work with it (Both in the Control Panel and the front end)

I managed to fix this problem, but now I get an "Error 500" on the front end, whenever I enter one of the sites other than the main one.

What could be causing this.

I have possibly nailed it down to being:

```
<?php require('./config.php'); ?>
```

In my "system/expressionengine/config/config.php" requesting my custom config file in the root directory. Could this be causing problems?

My custom config file can be found here:

https://github.com/madebymayo/ExpressionEngine-Environment-Config

EDIT: I must point out, that before placing my custom config in, the original config file worked perfectly for EE and MSM. But it doesn't really work with my workflow :)

## **PARTIALLY SOLVED...Still need help**

My current setup is to have my custom "config.php" bootstrap in the root of my site.

I then Have the require('./config.php') in both the database.php and config.php files within "/system/expressionengine/config/"

My URL's look like this:

http://website.com

http://website.com/website_1

http://website.com/website_2

Now I think the problem is the

```
<?php require('./config.php'); ?>
```

I changed it to (Added dot):

```
<?php require('../config.php'); ?>
```

and both my website_1 and website_2 work. But it breaks my Control Panel and the Root URL.

Is there an If statement I could put in my config file, to say IF we're inside either website_1 or website_2 display:

```
<?php require('../config.php'); ?>
```

But if we're inside the root or in the CP, use:

```
<?php require('./config.php'); ?>
```

Comment: do you have anything going on in an .htaccess file for the domains that are having problems?

Comment: @foamcow Nothing in htaccess. But I have figured out the problem, I just don't know the fix for it... See my edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/path/from/current/file/to/config.php');
```

For example, assuming you have config.php in the standard `system/expressionengine/config` directory, you would use this line:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../config.php');
```

Comment: This sort of does something, it changes the 500 error to:

Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Comment: hmm, I'm gonna guess if you're running locally on mamp it's not gonna be a php memory limit issue, but are there any plugins or anything a bit more "third party" in your config file that might just be conflicting with something else?

Comment: That should be the path from the current file, not the index. I updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Just ran into this and it solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: After trying again, many months after. This works!

Answer (score 0):

A useful trick I use in circumstances like this is to define an environment variable in an `.htaccess` file. These environment variables can then be accessed via PHP

So in website_1/ and website_2/, put the following line at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnv CONFIG_PATH_RELATIVE "../"
```

And then in the root site (where your control panel is), put the following line:

```
SetEnv CONFIG_PATH_RELATIVE "./"
```

Now, inside your main `config.php` file, at the top, do the following:

```
defined('CONFIG_PATH_RELATIVE') 
    || define('CONFIG_PATH_RELATIVE', (getenv('CONFIG_PATH_RELATIVE') ? getenv('CONFIG_PATH_RELATIVE') : FCPATH));
```

The above code says, "check for a constant named `CONFIG_PATH_RELATIVE`. If you find it, use it. If not, define that constant as the contents of the *environment variable* `CONFIG_PATH_RELATIVE`, and if you don't find an environment variable with that name, then use the EE built-in constant `FCPATH`."

Last, wherever you're requiring your custom config, change the statement to the following:

```
<?php require_once(CONFIG_PATH_RELATIVE.'config.php'); ?>
```

(Note that I've changed your `require` to a `require_once`. This is almost always better practice.)

The only real caveat is that some web hosts (usually the cheap ones) will not let you set environment vars in `.htaccess`. If you have one of those hosts, this technique will not work for you.

Comment: I just tried this (Running it locally on MAMP) and all of the site just gives me a 500 error now - CP and Front End?

Comment: Okay, that's pretty odd. A 500 error means something is wrong with Apache's configuration; frequently that's because of something in an .htaccess file. So I'm guessing that MAMP doesn't like putting environment variables in .htaccess files, by default; or else that it doesn't have the Apache module `mod_env` activated by default.

Unfortunately I hate Macs, so I know very little about how MAMP is set up out of the box. Hopefully someone can come along and shed some light on that.